# UIImage is null Xamarin forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Converting UIIMage to bye array like so to send to server:

```
  using (NSData imageData = originalImage.AsJPEG(.5f).GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None))
                    {

                        myByteArray = imageData.ToArray();
                    }
```

On the recipient side, UIImage is null when converting back:

```
       var nsdata = new NSData(Convert.ToBase64String(chatmedia.Media), NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None);

                        var uiimage = UIImage.LoadFromData(nsdata);
```

Comment: have you verified the Base64 data matches on both sides?

Comment: Hi, yes the length is the same on both sides

Comment: but does the content match?

Comment: It does.  I got it working now though.  I just skipped the step where I was converting it to an array.  Somehow that was messing it up.  Thanks!

Comment: Since you resolved this issue, it would be helpful to post your own answer and accept your own answer. This will help others who may have had the same issue know how you resolved it.

Comment: @jgoldberger I'd be glad to, but thought it was a no no to do that

Comment: I believe it is fine to do that, in fact I would think it is preferred so the people don't keep trying to answer it if it is already resolved. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  Basically instead of converting it to an array, I just used the value of the Base64 encoded string.  I was able to send that to the server, and decode it property from another client into an image

```
 myobject.Media = originalImage.AsJPEG(.5f).GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
```